# ROW_NUMBER with DATEADD not working well?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have date that I want to increment with 1 millisecond. I am using this sql,

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
    A VARCHAR(2)
)
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('a1')
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('b2')
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('a3')
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('b4')
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('a5')
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('b6')
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('a7')
INSERT INTO @A(A) VALUES ('b8')

SELECT DATEADD(millisecond, + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A), '2012-11-22     15:09:24.990'),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A)
FROM @A
```

But the result is,

```
2012-11-22 15:09:24.990 1
2012-11-22 15:09:24.993 2
2012-11-22 15:09:24.993 3
2012-11-22 15:09:24.993 4
2012-11-22 15:09:24.997 5
2012-11-22 15:09:24.997 6
2012-11-22 15:09:24.997 7
2012-11-22 15:09:24.997 8
```

which is incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DATETIME` datatype in SQL Server has a 3.33ms resolution.

You will **never** be able to create `15:09:24.991` and other values - what you're seeing is expected and [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

If you need greater accuracy - use the `DATETIME2` datatype instead (which can handle accuracy down to 100ns).

```
DECLARE @StartValue DATETIME2(3) = '20121122 15:09:24.990'

SELECT 
    @StartValue,
    DATEADD(Millisecond, 1, @StartValue),
    DATEADD(Millisecond, 2, @StartValue),
    DATEADD(Millisecond, 3, @StartValue)
```

generates results:

```
2012-11-22 15:09:24.990
2012-11-22 15:09:24.991
2012-11-22 15:09:24.992
2012-11-22 15:09:24.993
```

as you wanted.

**Update:** if you must stick with `DATETIME` - yes, you can add +3 and get these results:

```
DECLARE @StartValue DATETIME = '20121122 15:09:24.990'

SELECT 
    @StartValue, 
    DATEADD(Millisecond, 3, @StartValue),
    DATEADD(Millisecond, 6, @StartValue),
    DATEADD(Millisecond, 9, @StartValue)
```

gives you:

```
2012-11-22 15:09:24.990 
2012-11-22 15:09:24.993 
2012-11-22 15:09:24.997 
2012-11-22 15:09:25.000
```

Comment: I cannot change my db now. Any other solution. I can add 1 2 or 3, etc

Comment: No. You can only do what has been suggested or maybe add another column and use this to add more value.

Comment: Please update your answer with (Multiply)* 3. It working with this. Like SELECT DATEADD(millisecond, + 3 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A)...... It will be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increment the milliseconds of a date in this way.

This is taken from msdn:

> Milliseconds have a scale of 3 (.123), microseconds have a scale of 6
>   (.123456), And nanoseconds have a scale of 9 (.123456789). The time,
>   datetime2, and datetimeoffset data types have a maximum scale of 7
>   (.1234567). If datepart is nanosecond, number must be 100 before the
>   fractional seconds of date increase. A number between 1 and 49 is
>   rounded down to 0 and a number from 50 to 99 is rounded up to 100.

source:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)